# predict.svm function R text mining?

Tags: r, svm, text-mining

I have a training set that contains sentences and labels(1 et -1 ).
After creating an svm model. I want to predict the label and the score of my new data.
This is my code :

```
library(tm);
require(RcmdrPlugin.temis);
library(RTextTools);
require(e1071)
news=read.csv("C:..polarity.csv",header=F,sep=';') # the training data
traindata <- as.data.frame(news[1:196,]);
trainvector <- as.vector(traindata[,1]); # Choose the sentences without the labels
trainsource <- VectorSource(trainvector);
traincorpus <- Corpus(trainsource) # Create a training corpus
#Cleaning the training corpus
traincorpus <- tm_map(traincorpus,stripWhitespace)
traincorpus <- tm_map(traincorpus,tolower)
traincorpus <- tm_map(traincorpus, removeWords,stopwords("french"))
traincorpus <- tm_map(traincorpus,removeNumbers)
traincorpus <- tm_map(traincorpus, function(x)
gsub("(['’\n??]|[[:punct:]]|[[:space:]]|[[:cntrl:]])+", " ", x))
corpus1 <- Corpus(DirSource("C.../file", encoding="UTF-8"),
readerControl=list(language="fr"))  # Import the corpus of test
testcorpus=corpus1 # create a copy and cleaning it
testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus,stripWhitespace)
testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus,tolower)
testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus, removeWords,stopwords("french"))
testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus,removeNumbers)
testcorpus <- tm_map(testcorpus, function(x)
gsub("(['’\n??]|[[:punct:]]|[[:space:]]|[[:cntrl:]])+", " ", x))
#Creating the dtm of test and train corpus with words stemming 
tr_matrix <- create_matrix(traincorpus, language="french", stemWords=TRUE,
removeStopwords=TRUE,weighting=weightTf)
tr=as.matrix(tr_matrix)
ts_matrix <- create_matrix(testcorpus, language="french", stemWords=TRUE,
removeStopwords=TRUE,weighting=weightTf)
ts = as.matrix(ts_matrix)
y=traindata[,2]
model<-svm(y~tr)
pred=fitted(model)
pred <- predict(model, ts, decision.values = TRUE, probability = TRUE,na.action=TRUE)
```

I have this error : 
Erreur dans matrix(ret$dec, nrow = nrow(newdata), byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(rowns,  : 
la longueur de 'dimnames' [1] n'est pas égale à l'étendue du tableau
I guess it is because of the structure differnce between the training data and the new data.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what is in matrices 'tr' and 'ts'? I am guessing you do not have the variable names in your test set 'ts', or that they differ of those present in 'tr', which results in the svm-model not knowing how to handle the 'ts' input data. For example, give the R output of: "head(tr); head(ts)"

Comment: @TeemuDanielLaajala tr and ts are the DocumentTermMatrix for train and test data in which the words are lemmatised.

Comment: >str(ts)
    >num [1:10, 1:84] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    > - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
    > ..$ Docs : chr [1:10] " rencontre entre gens éduqués  civilisés 
    > ..$ Terms: chr [1:84] "abdelwaheb" "ãduquã" "alor">
    > str(tr)
    > num [1:196, 1:1026] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
   > attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
   > ..$ Docs : chr [1:196] " avant savait voleurs assassins ...
   > ..$ Terms: chr [1:1026] "â€œ""| __truncated__  truncated